# Eliminating Duplicate Strings and preserving only one in a string array

Tags: java, arrays, string

hello guys i am try to eliminate all the duplicate strings from a string of array and preserve only one string of that...

assume temp[] be the string array and contains

```
temp[0] = "stack";
temp[1] = "overflow";
temp[2] = "stack";
temp[3] = "stack";
temp[4] = "overflow";
```

i need only "stack" and "overflow" in this case (it may be stored into another string array) but preserving the order as

```
temp2[0] = "stack";
temp2[1] = "overflow";
```

assume temp2 be another string array..

Comment: What do you think about this problem? How would you try to solve it? Lets start from the bruteforce way.

Comment: @KingAslan Hover over the JavaScript tag, and read the tooltip carefully..

Comment: hashset doesnt keep order but more faster, linkedhashset keeps order but little bit more slower.

Comment: Please lookup carefully what exactly "jsp" and "javascript" are. Almost all of your questions were not in any way related to them.

Comment: sorry Rob W, balusC will not repeat it again...and thank you for ur suggestion....

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A `java.util.LinkedHashSet` will remove duplicates while preserving order.

```
temp = new LinkedHashSet<String>(Arrays.asList(temp)).toArray(new String[0]);
```

Answer (score 2):

Use `Set`

```
Set<String> uniqueStrings = new HashSet<String>();
uniqueStrings.add("Stack");
uniqueStrings.add("Overflow");
uniqueStrings.add("Stack");//ignored
```

Answer (score 0):

You ned to use a Set here:

```
Set<String> set = new HashSet<String>();
set.addAll(Arrays.asList(temp));
temp2 = set.toArray();
```